# can't recover my files in my thumbdrive

Tags: filesystems, usb-flash-drive, desktop-computer

I got a thumbdrive brand Kingston model DT101 G2 with capacity 32 GB. The problem is when I copy files from my computer to this thumbdrive, it seems I can't reopen it (files) at another computer when i connect this thumbdrive. although i don't classify my files to HIDDEN, it remains hidden eventho i used FOLDER OPTION to show the hidden files. however, this "hidden" files actually counquer up my thumbdrive's space. could you lend me help?

Comment: What OS do you run on these two computers? What filesystem is the thumbdrive formatted with? How do you determine the files are hidden? Please update the question.

Answer (score 0):

This is most likely caused by a virus hiding your files. I'm assuming you're running windows. There are a few things you can do. Firstly scan your computer for virus's and remove them, but this will not unhide your files. To unhide your files the easiest way is using the 'Run' command and typing `attrib * X: /s /d -s -h -r` where X = your thumbdrive letter. This will unhide all files on the drive and make them normal files.

Alternatively you can use the command prompt (as admin) to accomplish the same thing by navigating into your thumb drive then typing

```
attrib * /s /d -s -h -r
```

what these commands do is remove system/hidden/readonly status from all the contents of the thumbdrive